# bind function on submit in document ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am just learning javascript. How do I bind this function on submit in document ready?

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
       $(this).find(':select').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: show your html as well

Comment: You already are binding the function. Are you experiencing problems with your code?

Comment: Are you trying to keep the form from submitting until :select is disabled? Because as Patrick says, your binding is in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    /* your code here */
    $('form').bind('submit', function() {
       $(this).find(':select').removeAttr('disabled');
    });
    /* end your code */
});
```

It is as simple as that - once the document is "ready", the binding will be put in place - for more clarification, head over to the jQuery tutorial website for information regarding the $(document).ready() event: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Comment: `jQuery(function)` is shorthand for `$(document).ready(function)` so OP is already doing the binding.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options with jQuery for a document "ready" event :

`$(document).ready()`: When your dom is fully loaded, jQuery will trigger the ready event.

`$(document).load()` : jQuery waits until your dom and all your declared assets are loaded. So if you rely on css properties for your javascript code, use this one.

For additional information, please take a look at : http://api.jquery.com/ready/